# Expo/React-native android build cannot call remote API

Tags: android, react-native, axios, expo, eas

My eas/expo android build does not call the useEffect hook. Whenever I build it locally with expo run:android or expo go it works as expected and the hook is called. It works fine for ios both for local and eas builds as well. I tried running it on two android devices and the pixel 7 emulator. It never calls the hook. I tried calling the fetch event method from a button press and it calls the url but I get a Network error. Any help would be appreaciated. The url in the code is changed, my build calls a real api.

React native version: 0.72.3
Expo version: 49.0.6
Code:

```
const fetchEvents = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      };

  let url = 'http://localhost/api/externalevents';
  let searchParams = { searchText, fromDate, page, city, toDate };
  let searchParamsText = createSearchParams(searchParams);
  url = `${url}?${searchParamsText}`
  posthog?.capture("Fetching events: ", { url })

  let res = await axios.get<PagedResponse<ExternalEvent>>(url, { headers })
  if(res.status !== 200)
  {
    posthog?.capture('Failed to fetch events', { status: res.status, data: res.data })
    setIsLoading(false)
    return;
  }

  let oldData = [...externalEvents]
  let newData = res.data.data.map<ExternalEvent>((t) => ({ ...t, startsAt: new Date(t.startsAt) }));
  if (searchParams?.page === 1)
    setExternalEvents(newData);
  else setExternalEvents([...oldData, ...newData]);

  if (res.data.hasMore)
    setPage(page + 1);
  posthog?.capture('Events fetched')
  setHasMore(hasMore)
  setIsLoading(false)
  if (page === 1)
    listRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
      index: 0,
      animated: true
    })
  setDateModalIsOpen(false)
}
catch (error: any) {
  console.error(`Error while retrieving ExternalEvents: ${error}`);
  posthog?.capture('Failed to fetch events', { message: error.message, status: error.status })
  setIsLoading(false);
}
```

}

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await fetchEvents();
    })()
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android, network security configurations can affect whether network requests are allowed. Make sure your app's network_security_config.xml or related configuration files are correctly set up to allow network requests.

Answer (score 0):

Please put the following code in your Android manifest in the application tag.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `usesCleartextTraffic` to `true` to allow HTTP requests.

> The url in the code is changed, my build calls a real api.

This answer assumes the real API url is HTTP and not HTTPS. I got Network errors in a production build, but using development credentials and environment variables (to test the performance of the app). The generated Android app couldn't make the HTTP requests that used my local network ip over HTTP. I solved this issue as described at:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/24403#issuecomment-1733872085

In Expo `app.config.js` (or equivalent json file), add:

```
   "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "usesCleartextTraffic": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
```